# Conflict between the address of the local network and the computers behind OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, internal-dns

I have this situation: I implemented a VPN using the address `10.0.0.0/16`. Now, I'm on an office that have a local network on `10.0.0.0/16` too.

```
my computer ==> Local network ==> VPN
                 10.0.0.x         10.0.x.x
                Computer X        DNS
                 10.0.0.2         10.0.0.2
```

As you can imagine, when I connect to my VPN, there's a conflict with the addresses, starting with the OpenVPN's DNS server, on `10.0.0.2`. When I try to open a webpage, my computer it's routing the DNS queries to a local computer with address `10.0.0.2` that has nothing to do with the DNS server with the same number on the VPN. So, my computer can't resolve any name.

Change the VPN to a different address like `10.10.x.x/16` it's not possible. Change the local address to something different to `10.0.0.x/24` neither. What would be the best solution for this?

At first, I thought on configure OpenVPN on some way, so the DNS would be on something like 10.0.30.2. Is it possible? The second idea is to change the routing table every time I connect to the VPN (I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan).

Comment: `What would be the best solution for this` - You are screwed?  One of the networks needs to change.

Comment: I'm about to start to migrate the VPN to a different address space...

Comment: It won't help - you are screwed. No way around it, unless you want some semi-working environment, which you can achieve with mapping IPs from one of the networks to a virtual non-existant subnet, which the other network would have the route to. Basic services will work, but you'll never get something which has mitm-protection (like anything with word SSL in it) to work in that configuration...

Comment: Well, yes, I resigned to that situation. I'm finishing to migrate all the services to the new address. Thank you for your comments. I will leave this question here, open, as a monument about how I was screwed and I will never create again a VPN with common addresses like 10.0.0.x.